# Data fetched but doesn't show in the browser

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I am trying to retrieve the data from the mongodb and show them on the website. Handlebars are used for templates. Data is being successfully fetched which can be verified by printing them on console.

However data is not shown on the browser. Below are the key snippets of the my code.

Any help would be appreciated.

> routes/index.js

```
    const route=require('express').Router();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var azhwars=require('../models/azhwars');

route.get('/',function(req,res) {
    azhwars.find({},function (err, azhwars) {
        if(err) {
            return err;
        }
        console.log(azhwars.toString());
    });
    res.render('pages/home',{'title':"My Website",'azhwarsList':azhwars});
});

module.exports=route;
```

> models/azhwars.js

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

var AzhwarsSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports=mongoose.model('Azhwars',AzhwarsSchema);
```

> views/pages/home.hbs

```
{{#each azhwarsList}}
    <p>some {{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself figured it out. There was a logical error in the routes/index.js

```
 res.render('pages/home',{'title':"My Website",azhwarsList:azhwars});
```

Above should be called within the find method.

```
const route=require('express').Router();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var azhwars=require('../models/azhwars');

route.get('/',function(req,res) {
    azhwars.find({},function (err, azhwars) {
        if(err) {
            return err;
        }
        console.log(azhwars.toString());
        res.render('pages/home',{'title':"My Website",azhwarsList:azhwars});
    });

});
```

module.exports=route;